# Flutter :- HTTP File Post Example: Image

Tags: image, file, http, flutter, post

```
Future userPasswordUpdate() async {

    String passwordU = password.text;
    String confirmPasswordU = confirmPassword.text;
    String oldPasswordU = oldPassword.text;

    var url = 'url';

    var response = await http.put(url,
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json'
        },
        body: {
          "password": passwordU,
          "confirmPass": confirmPasswordU,
          "oldpassword": oldPasswordU,
        }
    );
```

I want to post image file to server with this method. But I Don't Know How. Can Anyone Help Me ?

Comment: Hi @Magatha ,please check the below solution andd let me know in case of concern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the image upload you can also use the **`Dio`** library to post image on server with requested parameters.Please check the below example of it.

```
Dio dio = new Dio(); // with default Options

// Set default configs
    dio.options.baseUrl = BASE_URL;
    dio.options.connectTimeout = 5000; //5s
    dio.options.receiveTimeout = 3000;
    dio.options.headers[HEADER_AUTH_TOKEN_KEY] = HEADER_AUTH_TOKEN_VALUE;
    dio.options.headers[HEADER_VERSION_KEY] = HEADER_VERSION_VALUE;



    FormData formData = new FormData.fromMap({
      "password": passwordU,
      "confirmPass": confirmPasswordU,
      "oldpassword": oldPasswordU,


      "YOUR_IMAGE_PARAMETER_NAME": await MultipartFile.fromFile(imageFile.path,filename: imageFile.path.split("/").last),

    });

    var response = await dio.post(REGISTRATION_URL, data: formData);

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      apiResponse.onSuccess(response.toString(), eventType);
      print("Image Uploaded");
    } else {
      apiResponse.onError('Failed to load post');
      print("Upload Failed");
    }
  }
```

Inside the pubspec.yaml used this library,

> **dio: ^3.0.9**

For the info about the library , you need to check this link [Click](https://pub.dev/packages/dio)

Comment: Still Im Getting Error Like  Unhandled Exception: DioError [DioErrorType.RESPONSE]: Http status error [422]

Comment: I have updated the solution, you need to take care of both**BASE_URL** and **REGISTRATION_URL** like in your base url there is only url like http//www.xxxxxx.com and in your REGISTRATION_URL there  is futher name like "updateProfile.php"

Comment: Thank You, I Think It's Worked. Thank You Soo Much

Comment: @Magtha, happy to help you..keep happy coding