# serving audio files and images via http server from dart:io

Tags: flutter, audio, dart

I am trying to serve audioFiles via http using `HttpServer` of the `dart:io`. my current code doesn't behave as needed as when going to the url of a specific file on my browser expecting to get the default browser player for the audio file what I get is the string representation of the file as if I opened it in a text editor.

here is my code for the request handling :

```dart
_handleGet(HttpRequest request) {
      final String fileID = request.uri.queryParameters["fileID"];
      String fileUri = filesToServe[fileID.split(".")[0]];
      if(fileUri!=null){
        final File file = new File(fileUri);
        file.exists().then((bool found) {
          if (found) {
            request.response.headers.contentType = ContentType.binary;
            file.openRead().pipe(request.response).catchError((e) {print(e);});
            request.response.contentLength = file.statSync().size;
            request.response.addStream(file.openRead());

          } else {
            _sendNotFound(request.response);
          }
        });
      }else{
        _sendNotFound(request.response);
      }

    }
```

I am comparing this behavior to the files got from using `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8080` to render a folder available to the network. The music files are read easily by the browser and I want the same behavior with dart.

Comment: Try this solution, might be helpful for you ,please check it once  https://stackoverflow.com/a/61222561/3946958

Comment: most likely `Content-Type` header is wrong

Comment: @pskink it was but I had to add it manually the audio/mpeg content type was not included in the presets, only binary, text and json