# How to pass image from camera capture into server?

Tags: api, rest, flutter, dart, imagepicker

Get the image from here.

```
Future getImage () async {

   File image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);

   setState(() {
     imagePhoto = image;
   });

}
```

And pass here.

```
Future upload (File image, File image2) async {
   FormData formData = new FormData.fromMap({
     "image": await MultipartFile.fromFile(image.path,filename: image.path.split("/").last),
     "signature": MultipartFile.fromFileSync(imagePhoto.path,filename: imagePhoto.path.split("/").last),
     "latitude": "${_currentPosition.latitude}, ${_currentPosition.longitude}",
   });
}
```

This process giving me error 422. The problem is the image is from camera, if gallery means it's pass successful.

Comment: can you attach the error log..

Comment: refer this link , might be helpful for you https://stackoverflow.com/a/61222561/3946958